# MySQL port 3306 closed even with ufw inactive and bind-address and skip-networking commented

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, networking

I'm trying to connect to mysql remmotely but the port is closed (used telnet and other methods).
I did the following checks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Already commented bind-address and skip-networking lines in mysqld.cnf. Using Ubuntu 18.04

PS: I can access mysql through localhost normally.

Answer (score 0):

you have to allow the ip of the machine on which you are trying to access the remote mysql server.suppose you have a vm on which mysql resides.Then you are trying to communicate with mysql from your local system.so go the vm and allow your local system ip in mysql.I forgot the exact mysql commands, but you can find it on google.enable ufw also.do sudo ufw allow 3306.this might help.
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: I already set bind-address to 0.0.0.0 which is supposed to allow every external IP and it did not work either.

Comment: do it like this.
 >   mysql -u root -p
>mysql> GRANT ALL ON fooDatabase.* TO fooUser@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
change "1.2.3.4" with ip of your local system.
please refer to this https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/

Comment: The problem is not with the user. The port itself is closed. It is not possible even to connect into the service to choose the user... The user "Juned" in the other answer figured out it could be an AWS firewall blocking the port which I'm gonna check later.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this answers your case given what your `iptables` output looks like, but let me record it here regardless since it's not covered by any of the answers to the similar questions:

I ran into the same problem, around the same time, and in my case it was indeed a simple firewall issue: With Debian (Stretch) switching its default firewall backend to `nf_tables`, the `ufw` rules would stop working and in particular, `ufw allow 3306/tcp` would do nothing at all; in particular, the rule for 3306 would have no effect, regardless of whether `ufw` was enabled or, as in your case, disabled.

Indeed `iptables` would cover none of the `ufw` rules, but these were, however, available through `iptables-legacy`. As such, the workaround that ended up doing the trick in my case was to shift back to `iptables-legacy`, through

```
update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
```

and reloading `ufw`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to uncomment/modify bind address configuration in `/etc/my.cnf` under `mysqld` section

For Example:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

You can setup specific IP or if you set it to `0.0.0.0` connection will be allowed from any machine.

Comment: I already set bind-address to 0.0.0.0 but it did not work either.

Comment: Did you restart mysql services after changing my.cnf file ?

Comment: Is your mysql server and the machine from where you're trying in same network ? Please share the screenshot of your mysql restart and mysql connection command.

Comment: No. I'm using an AWS server and trying to access it from my local machine. I can only access mysql via putty (as localhost).

Comment: If you're trying to access it from your local machine then the public IP of your network should be allowed in AWS firewall for incoming connection to that specific port.

Comment: I have not used aws,But worked with azure.I can say even if you are allowing any port in the instance, still you need to allow the same port from azure admin portal.Please check if something like this in aws also.